# Copy to another sheet with filter script gs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

And thanks for your help. Sorry for my English :)

Google tables have a limit for rows. So.
How can I change a code copy to other sheets with filter >
IF( row  C OR D OR F NOT NULL > copy)

```
sheet1.getRange("A2:F61").copyTo(sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow()+1,1,1,5), {contentsOnly:true});
ss.getRangeList(['C2:D60', 'F61']).activate().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true})
ss.getRange('K57').activate();
ss.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).activate();
```

I need only dates on the picture

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to scan every row for it to work, since you can't just consider the entire column, so a `for` loop can help you.

```
for (i = 2, i <= ss.getLastRow(), i++){ 
  if (ss.getRange("C"+i).getValue() != "" || ss.getRange("D"+i).getValue() != "" || ss.getRange("F"+i).getValue() != "") {
     //your copy code here
  }
}
```

This will compare only one cell for each given row and column.

Comment: Rodrigo! Thanks a lot and hugs! I'll try! I hope, I'll do it!